# Comparing each element of the defaultdict(list) and find matching elements

Tags: python

I have a defaultdict(list) that looks like this

```
{'device_A': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.2/24', '192.168.1.3/24'],
'device_B': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.20/24', '192.168.1.21/24'],
'device_C': ['192.168.1.21/24', '192.168.1.30/24']}
```

for the dictionary above, i need to check whether each of the IP address in device A exist in device B and device C, and IP address in device B exist in device A and device C, and lastly IP address in device C exist in device A and device B.

Any way to do the comparison?

Edit: My data is quite large consisting roughly 140 devices x 2000 data so efficiency is quite important here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid brute-forcing, you could turn the dictionary around and compute

```
device_to_ip = {'device_A': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.2/24', '192.168.1.3/24'],
'device_B': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.20/24', '192.168.1.21/24'],
'device_C': ['192.168.1.21/24', '192.168.1.30/24']}
ip_to_device = defaultdict(set)
for device_name, ip_addresses in device_to_ip.items():
    for ip_address in ip_addresses:
        ip_to_device[ip_address].add(device_name)

for ip_address, device_names in ip_to_device.items():
    print(f"Devices with IP address {ip_address}: {device_names}")
```

This algorithm runs through each list item twice. However, this might come with more memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force is something like this:

```
import itertools
t = {'device_A': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.2/24', '192.168.1.3/24'],
'device_B': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.20/24', '192.168.1.21/24'],
'device_C': ['192.168.1.21/24', '192.168.1.30/24']}

for (k_i, v_i), (k_j, v_j) in itertools.combinations(t.items(), 2):
    overlap = set(v_i) & set(v_j)
    if k_i != k_j:
        if len(overlap) > 0:
            print('overlapping items, from %s and %s: %s' % (k_i, k_j, str(overlap)))


>>> overlapping items, from device_A and device_B: {'192.168.1.1/24'}
>>> overlapping items, from device_B and device_C: {'192.168.1.21/24'}
```

Is this what you're looking for? I'm not sure what output format you want but without hashing I'm pretty sure this is as good as it gets.

One way to speed up the computation is to use `defaultdict(set)` instead of `defaultdict(list)`. Alternatively, if you can't access that part of the code, you can just preprocess using:

```
t = {k:set(v) for k, v in t.items()}
```

Preprocessing depends on whether (1) you can alter the original object or not, (2) if not, then preprocessing saves time at the expense of memory. The trade-off is yours to make.

## Updated

I'm not quite sure I understand the explanation you gave, but it's also 10PM right before a major conference deadline for me and I shouldn't be procrastinating like this, but I am. This will test in both directions.

```
import itertools
t = {'device_A': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.2/24', '192.168.1.3/24'],
'device_B': ['192.168.1.1/24', '192.168.1.20/24', '192.168.1.21/24'],
'device_C': ['192.168.1.21/24', '192.168.1.30/24']}

for (k_i, v_i), (k_j, v_j) in itertools.product(t.items(), t.items()):
    overlap = set(v_i) & set(v_j)
    if k_i != k_j:
        if len(overlap) > 0:
            print('overlapping items, from %s and %s: %s' % (k_i, k_j, str(overlap)))


>>> overlapping items, from device_A and device_B: {'192.168.1.1/24'}
>>> overlapping items, from device_B and device_A: {'192.168.1.1/24'}
>>> overlapping items, from device_B and device_C: {'192.168.1.21/24'}
>>> overlapping items, from device_C and device_B: {'192.168.1.21/24'}
```

Comment: Note for switching to `set` - it will shuffle the lists randomly. Depending on the situation, this may or may not be an issue...

Comment: not quite yet, what I am looking at is device A compare with device B and device C, device B compare with device A and device C, device C compare with device A and device B, the reason is that even though we've compare A vs B and get the result, but there might be IP addresses where IP address in B is within the network segment of device A but not the other way round, so I need to compare each of the IP even though it might had been compared in the previous devices.

Comment: @ReverseEngineer see edits